# How to send existing photos to photo stream?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, photo-stream

I just enabled iCloud on my iPad. I've also downloaded iPhoto on my Mac to sync my photos on the iPad. The problem is that I can only get pictures that I downloaded after I enabled iCloud on my iPad.

Is there a way to add all the photos to photo stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag the photos from the album to your photo stream. Careful though; I did this and can't find a way to undo what I've added to my photo stream!

Comment: I don't seem to find a way to act as described on my iPad 3: When chosing "Albums" in my pictures I cannot drag and drop my camera roll. And when I go into my fotos from my camera roll I can select a couple of pictures but I cannot drag and drop them anywhere; and I cannot drag and drop them singly either.

Comment: I believe @pully6 meant you had to drag photos on iPhoto, on a Mac.